# Improving speed of Sql query

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I'm working with a Sql Server database that is used to track documents and am trying to find documents that are duplicates based on four values stored in indexTables.  What I have so far is incredibly slow.  Is there a way to speed this up?

```
select d.ID, d2.ID
from DOCUMENTS d
inner join IndexTable1 itm on d.ID = itm.ID 
inner join IndexTable2 pd on d.ID = pd.ID 
inner join IndexTable3 amt on d.ID = amt.ID 
inner join IndexTable4 acct on d.ID = acct.ID 
inner join DOCUMENTS d2 on d.ID <> d2.ID
inner join IndexTable06 itm2 on d2.ID = itm2.ID and itm.VALUE=itm2.VALUE
inner join IndexTable07 pd2 on d2.ID = pd2.ID and pd2.VALUE = pd.VALUE
inner join IndexTable03 amt2 on d2.ID = amt2.ID and amt.VALUE = amt2.VALUE
inner join IndexTable13 acct2 on d2.ID = acct2.ID and acct.VALUE = acct2.VALUE
```

Further information:
Running "Display estimated execution plan" shows that the biggest hits come on doing a Clustered Index Seek on IndexTable2 (37%) and IndexTable3(35%).

Comment: Have you run this in Query Analyzer/Management Studio, and shown the execution plan?  If so, what were the worst performating sections?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the foreign key columns involved in those JOINs ? Are your index statistics up to date (if not: update them!)?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Added that information to the question

Comment: The FK's constraints are trusted ? `SELECT fk.is_not_trusted, * FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WHERE fk.is_not_trusted=1`

Comment: @BogdanSahlean that query returns no rows